# Username check is not working when user registers -asp.net

Tags: c#, registration

i want to check if the username already exists in the database and if yes, error message will prompt that says "username already exist". now i have this code but its not working. program still accepts the username even if it is duplicated from the database. can someone help me out pls? here is my whole registration code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1) // check if user already exist.
            {
                Response.Write("User already existing");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["Contact"]= txtContact.Text;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
            Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
            label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
            //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You validate data on Page_Load? I think, you can choose to these solusions

1. You have to do it in btn_Registration_Click before you insert the
   data, or
2. Maybe, you can modify it to do in sp and throw message through it if data is
       duplicated and do the checking there.

It should be like this (according to solution 1)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp > 0) // check if user already exist.
            {
                Response.Write("User already existing");
            }
            else
            {
                string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
                scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

                scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Session["Contact"]= txtContact.Text;
                Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
                Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
                label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
                //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: ive tried it but still accepting the same usernames @Heinz Siahaan

Comment: Do you try my edited code like above? I change  if `(temp == 1) ` to  `if (temp > 0)`  to accomodate probability you inserted user more than one with same username before.

Comment: .yes sir. its not reading the 2nd "scm" in the else part. it says it is already used as a parent scope to denote something else. @Heinz Siahaan

Comment: its working! great!!  thanks a lot. can the error message "user already exists" be there before the register click? like when i typed in the same user, error message pops up immediately?

Comment: I think it's not something you can do with c# alone. Maybe you can do it with other technology combine within it (e.g. jquery, AJAX or something like that)

Comment: okay im on it. really want to thank you @Heinz Siahaan.Godbless :)